# Techniques and algorithms for precise and efficient graph plotting

Tags: algorithm, 2d, precision, plot, graphing

I'd like to plot mathematical functions and I'm looking for techniques and algorithms for precise and efficient plotting. 2D plotting should suffice. I focus on techniques and algorithms, not libraries or languages. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for techniques like [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm)? That page links to related algorithms.

Comment: +1 thanks. I'm looking for techniques to drawing curves with high precision